# Magento2: How to display product attribute in frontend

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, frontend

I use this code to display one attribute in frontend:

```
<?php 
    $optionText = '';
    $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('newbrand_name');

    if ($attr->usesSource()) {
       $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getNewbrandName());
    }
?>
<?php if($optionText){ ?>
    <div class="attributes-list"><?php echo "Producent: " ?><?php echo $optionText ?></div>
<?php } ?>
```

Working correctly.

Can anyone help me modify this code to display two additional attributes? Color and Gender from attribute code:

- color
- gender

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `getAttributeText` to get the value of product attribute.

```
<?php 
    $optionText = '';
    $attr = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('newbrand_name');

    if ($attr->usesSource()) {
       $optionText = $attr->getSource()->getOptionText($_product->getNewbrandName());
    }
?>
<?php if($optionText){ ?>
    <div class="attributes-list"><?php echo "Producent: " ?><?php echo $optionText ?></div>
<?php } ?>

<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('color')) : ?>
    <?php $optionValue = $_product->getAttributeText('color'); ?>
    <div class="attributes-list"><?php echo "Color: " ?><?= $optionValue; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php if($_product->getAttributeText('gender')) : ?>
    <?php $optionValue = $_product->getAttributeText('gender'); ?>
    <div class="attributes-list"><?php echo "Gender: " ?><?= $optionValue; ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: working perfect. I have the last question. Do you have any solution how to display this all attributes in one line? https://prnt.sc/ukw7pq

Comment: sorry, that's the CSS change you need to do for that.